# Does 'find' traverse a directory if '-not -path "*/FolderName/*" ' is used?

Tags: command-line, find

I'm using `find "/home/../.." -type f -not -path "*/FolderName/*"` to ignore 
*FolderName* from being listed. However, I read that `find` still traverses this *FolderName*. Searching for files in this folder using the upper command doesn't list any, so I'm not sure if the folder is still being traversed or not. `-prune` is said to really ignore the folder from being traversed, but I'm not sure if `-prune` is really needed?

Comment: Without traversing everything in `FolderName/`, how can `find` know if which paths in it don't match `*/FolderName/*`?

Comment: Good point. I read it supposed to be with the asterisks, otherwise 'find' would list the folder.

Comment: I believe `find` is *required* to traverse everything in `FolderName` (even though it won't get printed) because it has to print an error message and exit with a non-zero status if the traversal encounters an error (such as an unreadable directory).  That is, `mkdir -p foo/bar/baz && chmod -r foo/bar && find foo -not -path 'foo/*'` still has to print an error that it couldn't read `foo/bar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-depth` (and `-delete` implies `-depth`), `-prune`, `-maxdepth <n>`, `-depth [+-]<n>`, `-follow` (now replaced with the `-L` option), `-quit`, `-exit`, `-xdev`/`-mount` predicates (not all implementations support all of them) are the only ones that affect the directory traversal.

Here, instead of

```
... ! -path '*/whatever/*' ...
```

You can do:

```
... \( ! -name whatever -o -prune \) ...
```

Or if you also want to exclude `whatever` itself (which `! -path '*/whatever/*'` doesn't):

```
... -name whatever -prune -o \( ... \)
```

Those would have to be inserted *before* predicates like `-type f`.

That  also avoids the problems whereby `*` doesn't match sequence of bytes that don't translate to characters in some locales and some implementations (like GNU `find` in most common locales).

So for your example:

```
find "/home/../.."  \( ! -name FolderName -o -prune \) -type f -print
```

Or:

```
find "/home/../.." -name FolderName -prune -o \( -type f -print \)
```

(note that it excludes all files called `FolderName` even those that are not of type *directory*).

Comment: Thank you for the full command. Good to know that the ordner of commands is also of importance. I hope it's correct now: find "/home/../Backup" \( ! -name "FolderToIgnore" -o -prune \) -type f -printf. It doesn't list FolderToIgnore in the output (it seems FolderToIgnore itself is also ignored this way?) .

Comment: @linuxuser, it's your `-type f` that filters it out as it's not a regular file. If you remove the `-type f`, it should turn up (and not in the other approach).

Comment: Thanks. I added the mentioned `... -name "FolderToIgnore" -prune -o \( ... \) ...` before and it indeed works (as expected also without the `-type` option): `find "/home/../Backup" -name "FolderToIgnore" -prune -o \( ! -name "FolderToIgnore" -o -prune \) -printf [...]` Do I still need to add `... \( ! -name "FolderToIgnore" -o -prune \) ...`? `... -name whatever -prune -o  ...` also ignores the folder.

Comment: @linuxuser, no, no need for all that. The command lines as I gave them should be enough. `-prune` always returns _true_ but as a side effect tells `find` not to descend into the directory. `\( ! -name FolderName -o -prune \)` returns _true_ for every file (but prunes the `FolderName` ones). `-name FolderName -prune` returns true only for the files named `FolderName` (and prunes them), and with `-o something-else`, we do `something-else` for the files that are not called `FolderName`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

`find` will enter and traverse everything under the given path even if the path is filtered out using `-not -path` or `! -path`.

This is because the `-path` predicate doesn't affect the traversal that `find` does.  It only affects the filtering of the found path names.

To stop `find` from descending into a particular path, use `-prune` instead.